# Ionic 3 Ion-toggle handle icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic3

How can I display an ionic icon on the handle like that:

[image]

I couldn’t find a way to access the handle via css.

Thanks

Comment: You need to write custom control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with CSS.  There's no need to write a custom control.

I've added a class `rainy-toggle`, then just added the following CSS. I used an SVG in base64 below, but you can add the image how you choose.

Because the 'native' Android toggle looks different, I would just override the styles for the `toggle-md`, substituting the iOS CSS for your rainy-toggle.  In other words, you'll have to modify **all** of the toggle styles to override them on Android devices.

**CSS:**

```
.toggle-ios.toggle-checked.rainy-toggle .toggle-inner {
    background: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 80%;
    background-color: white;
    background-position: center;
}

.toggle-ios.toggle-checked.rainy-toggle .toggle-icon {
    background-color: #0082FF;
}
```

[image: Icon Toggle]

Comment: Great, it helped me, thanks

Comment: How would you do this with ionic 4? It uses shadow dom, is this even possible?

Comment: @Kelvijn I haven't tried it, but there are custom css properties (how to modify shadow DOM styles) for the background of the toggle exposed on the toggle component. See the doc here: https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/toggle/ and for an explanation of how to use them, see here: https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-variables